# Defining a Struct with attributes determined at runtime

Tags: ruby

I've noticed Ruby's philosophy of keeping as many things flexible in the run time as possible.

Here is a typical (for the best of my knowledge) Ruby struct definition:

```
    Person = Struct.new("Person", :name, :address)
    Person.new("John", "Chicago, IL")
```

My question is, is it possible to define a structure in run-time when the list of structure fields / members is also defined in the run time? Something that would look like this:

```
    Person = Struct.new("Person", list_of_structure_fields)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just [splat](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/22/rubys-splat-operator/%5C) an array:

```
fields = [:name, :address]
Person = Struct.new("Person", *fields)
Person.new("John", "Chicago, IL")
#=> #<struct Struct::Person name="John", address="Chicago, IL">
```

This allows you to do some fun things:

```
person = {name: "John", address: "Chicago, IL"}
Person = Struct.new("Person", *person.keys)
Person.new(*person.values)
#=> #<struct Struct::Person name="John", address="Chicago, IL">
```

Answer (score 3):

[OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) is designed to do just that:

```
require 'ostruct'
h = {name: "John", address: "Chicago, IL"}
person = OpenStruct.new(h)
puts person.name #=> John
person.age  = 35 # freely add fields and values
```